# Как авторизоваться с помощью curl?

Tags: php, curl, парсер

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте http://www.mysite.com, но что-то мешает. Форма авторизации содержит кроме логина и пароля еще поля, но если не ошибаюсь они необязательные. Этот скрипт мне возвращает страницу с непройденной формой авторизации. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться)

```
$login_url = "http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx";
$post_data = '3dcclogin=mypost@yandex.ru&3dccpassword=123456';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT     , 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT   5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091016 Firefox/3.5.4');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');

$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
echo $postResult;
```

Comment: При авторизации отправляется два запроса последовательно. В первом только логин, во втором весь набор полей в JSON, а не post параметрами. Изучите взаимодействие формы авторизации и бэкэнда предже, чем писать скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте этот код для незаконных действий

```
<?php

$login_url = "http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx/Login";
$post_data = 'loginData='.json_encode([
    'Login' => 'mypost@yandex.ru',
    'Password' => "123456", 
    'RememberMe' => false, 
    'LoginAsSupplier'=> false, 
    'CatalogId' => ""
]);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT   5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091016 Firefox/3.5.4');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');

$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
echo $postResult;
```

Сервер ничего не вернул, но cookie записалось. Считаю, что авторизацию прошел. В браузере то же поведение.

Comment: Да, куки на месте, но в браузер не возвращается ничего...буду дальше думать, спасибо